# How do I restrict regular expression from taking certain words

Tags: c#, regex

I have created a regular expression Regex for string that starts from " and ends with " eg: "mynameis"

"\"(?:[^\"\\]|\\.)*\""

Now I want that this expression must not take {we, us, they, and} words.
How do I do that?
For instance if I input "mynameisalexand"
Compiler must ignore {and} and take this string as "mynameisalex"

Comment: And if the input is `"mynamesarealexandandrew"`? Should it be `"mynamesarealexrew"`?

Comment: Yeah! and is just used as an example. There are other words that I would restrict. I just need an idea!

Comment: Can't you just use usual string manipulation methods on the captured string?

Comment: I'm creating a tokenizer for compiler, lexical analyzer.

Comment: Match with the expression you have (or unroll it for better performance) and when you get the matches, just remove these substrings. There is no way to match non-continuous text.

Comment: See [this demo](http://ideone.com/GMRiMh).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there is no way to match non-continuous text with regex, you can still use your regex or an unrolled one:

```
"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%22%5B%5E%22%5C%5C%5D*(%3F%3A%5C%5C.%5B%5E%22%5C%5C%5D*)*%22&i=%22mynamesarealexandandrew%22)

and remove the substrings you defined with a mere `String.Replace` (or with a regex like `we|and|...`).

See the [C# demo](http://ideone.com/GMRiMh):

```
var input = "\"mynamesarealexandandrew\" \"mynameisalexand\"";
var regex = new Regex(@"""[^""\\]*(?:\\.[^""\\]*)*""", RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);
var results = regex.Matches(input).Cast<Match>()
                   .Select(p => p.Value.Replace("we", "")
                                       .Replace("us", "")
                                       .Replace("they", "")
                                       .Replace("and", ""))
                   .ToList();
foreach (var s in results)    // DEMO
{
    Console.WriteLine(s);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to clean the string up afterwards; regex just isn't powerful enough.

In fact, what you've got is a context-free grammar! If we call your acceptable tokens an 'id', then you've defined a language that looks like this;

```
id (('and'|'we'|'us') id?)*
```

That is, at least one id; then the words `and`, `we`, or `us`, then another possible id, maybe. The whole thing then repeats, allowing you to match

mynameisandrewbutheyarebothcalledsarah

as 
   id: mynameis
   'and'
   id: rewbut
   'they'
   id: arebothcalledsarah

So, this is what's known as a context-free language, and regex can't parse that kind of thing. Your best bet is to split on the unacceptable words and just stitch them together at the end.